# Go - cross compile error (mac -> windows)

Tags: go, cross-compiling

GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ HOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 CGO_CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include --sysroot /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64" CGO_LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib --sysroot /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64" go build github.com/paulsmith/gogeos/geos

I'm trying to cross compile (MacOS -> Windows)
But I'm having really trouble with this. Please help me guys

Error message is here
/usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o:cwrappers.cgo2:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `GEOSArea_r' /usr/local/Cellar/mingw-w64/9.0.0_2/toolchain-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b001/_x003.o:cwrappers.cgo2:(.text+0xe0): undefined reference to` GEOSBoundary_r'
...

Comment: Maybe it's the problem with the go package.. I tried to cross compile with other go packages using c/c++ libraries and they had no problems

Comment: Hi ! Is the required version of the project (defined in the go.mod) is the same as the one with which you try to compile the code on your MacOS ?

Comment: https://github.com/paulsmith/gogeos/
I can't find go.mod in this project. Can u find it?

Comment: It looks very old project I guess.. the last commit is like 2014.
Maybe I shoud find another package Haha

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.